# In Idiocracy was there any indication about the use of AI?

Tags: idiocracy

It looked like things were very automated -- somehow they kept producing monster trucks and machine guns. Perhaps the AI itself had degraded over time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AI doesn't seem to exist in Idiocracy but there are automatic computerised systems in place. We see a few of them;

- The auto-layoff software used by Brawndo
- The Prison Management software
- The auto-doc

All three of these systems appear to be effective as '*single function software*' but there's no sign of intelligence in this film, artificial or otherwise.

Comment: This is a very good answer and the writers must have struggled to explain how to make the world work to the extent it does and yet still be facing problems that literally would kill every human within a year or two had Joe not arrived.